# Does every recipient receive a different version of "encrypted" email using PGP?

Tags: encryption, pgp, rsa

If I understood it correctly, PGP encrypts email by using receiver's public key. In a multiple-receiver scenario, does that mean each receiver will get a different version of "encrypted" email but the same version of "decrypted" email?

Also, it is possible to decrypt email with sender's public key?

Comment: In public/private key cryptography, it is not possible to decrypt anything with the same key that encrypted it. So to answer the implied question no, you do not have to keep someone's public key a secret. Nor should you keep your own public key a secret.

Comment: dupe  https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8245/gpg-file-size-with-multiple-recipients and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/74469/how-to-encrypt-group-emails and more on other Stacks

Answer (score 2):

> In a multiple-receiver scenario, does that mean each receiver will get a different version of "encrypted" email but the same version of "decrypted" email?

Usually not.  PGP supports something called "Multi-Key Encryption"; multiple recipients public keys are used to encrypt the data encryption key, which is minimal overhead on top of what is already being encrypted.  [Here's a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597188/encryption-with-multiple-different-keys) that can tell you more about that.

> Also, it is possible to decrypt email with sender's public key?

No, public keys are used to encrypt and to verify signatures.  A single key half (either the public or private key) can't be used to both encrypt and decrypt; they're one-way tools.

Answer (score 0):

The message is encrypted by random symmetric key, then for every recipient the symmetric key is encrypted with his public key and included into the pgp file (there will be several copies of the symmetric key, encrypted with different public keys, in one file). So every receiver would get the same encrypted message.

No, you can't decrypt anything with **public** key, otherwise everyone would be able to (it's public, everyone can get it). But for example Enigmail by default encrypts the message with both recipient's and sender's public keys (as though sender is one of receivers), so that sender can decrypt the message in his "Sent" folder.

Answer (score 0):

### Simply try:

#### Preamble:

From `man gpg`:

> ```
> NAME
>        gpg - OpenPGP encryption and signing tool
> ...
> COMMANDS
>        -e     Encrypt data...
> OPTIONS
>        -a     Create  ASCII  armored  output...
>        -r     Encrypt for user id name...
> ```

#### Encryption for one recipient

```
$ gpg -aer $USER  <<<"Hello world." >/tmp/file1.pgp
$ ls -l /tmp/file1.pgp
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 533 nov  9 15:39 /tmp/file1.pgp

$ gpg -qd /tmp/file1.pgp
Hello world.

$ gpg -aer aFriendOfMine <<<"Hello world." >/tmp/file1.pgp
$ ls -l /tmp/file1.pgp
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 533 nov  9 15:42 /tmp/file1.pgp

$ gpg -qd /tmp/file1.pgp
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

Nota: I have *`aFriendOfMine`*'s public key, but I can't decrypt the message I crypted with his public key.

This answer your second question.

#### Encryption for many recievers

```
$ gpg -aer $USER -r aFriendOfMine <<<"Hello world." >/tmp/file1.pgp
$ ls -l /tmp/file1.pgp
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 902 nov  9 15:43 /tmp/file1.pgp
```

The file is something bigger!

```
$ gpg -qd /tmp/file1.pgp
Hello world.
```

And I know *`aFriendOfMine`* could decrypt same message too.

You could add many `-r $DEST` flag on command line, but as many dests, the mail become bigger, depending on number of recipient AND keylength and algorithm of each recipient's key.

```
$ gpg -aer $USER -r aFriendOfMine -r alice -r bruno -r charlie -r theDude \
      <<<"Hello world." >/tmp/file1.pgp
$ ls -l /tmp/file1.pgp
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 3027 nov  9 16:26 /tmp/file1.pgp
```

The file is something bigger, but each recipient will be able to read them.